OAuth2 issue with Spring Boot 3 & Reactive WebClient
I have created a Spring Boot (3.2.5) app that makes use of the reactive WebClient.  I configured the WebClient with the Client Credentials authorization grant type because the application needs to run as a service.
When I attempt a request, I can see that it is trying to authenticate but failing to get the auth token.  This is the error:
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_client] Bad credentials
Here is my code:
WebClientConfig.java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Value("${web.client.base.url}")
    private String webClientBaseUrl;

    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.sap.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
                                                                    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.sap.client-id}") String clientId,
                                                                    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.sap.client-secret}") String clientSecret) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("sap")
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .build();

        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("sap");

        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(webClientBaseUrl)
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }

}

TestService.java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class TestService {

    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public TestService(WebClient webClient, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60_000)
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        webClient.post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/v2/inference/deployments/xxxxxxxxx/chat/completions?api-version=2024-02-01")
                        .build())
                .bodyValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Payload(List.of(new Message("user", "What is the answer to universe?")))))
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Object.class))
                .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error: {}", error.getMessage()))
                .block(Duration.of(10_000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
    }

The stacktrace:
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_client] Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.lambda$authorize$0(ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:86) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://api.prod.eu-central-1.com/v2/inference/deployments/xxxxxxxxxx/chat/completions%3Fapi-version=2024-02-01 [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.lambda$authorize$0(ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:86) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$27(Mono.java:3840) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$29(Mono.java:3930) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxHide.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:149) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2097) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:446) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:500) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:793) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1475) ~[netty-handler-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1349) ~[netty-handler-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1389) ~[netty-handler-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:146) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1807) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at com.amista.mailmonitor.TestService.test(TestService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_client] Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.oauth2AccessTokenResponse(OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from POST https://gen-ai-hub-test-extended-plan-12345678.authentication.eu10.com/oauth/token [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.oauth2AccessTokenResponse(OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2097) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.5.jar:3.6.5]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:446) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:500) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:793) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.18.jar:1.1.18]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1475) ~[netty-handler-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1349) ~[netty-handler-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1389) ~[netty-handler-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

If I try authenticate using Postman with the same settings and credentials, it works fine and I get the auth token.
I have verified that the clientId, clientSecret etc. are all correct as I'm using the same in Postman.
I have tried encoding the clientId and clientSecret, but it makes no difference.
Has anyone set up OAuth2 with the WebClient in Spring Boot 3? Am I missing something in my code?
Thanks in advance!

Ok, turns out it was the ClientAuthenticationMethod that was the problem.  I changed it to CLIENT_SECRET_POST and now it works fine.
